# C#: What is the difference between CompareTo(String) and Equals(String)?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to know, when comparing string in C#? which method is suitable to use and why?

`CompareTo()` or `Equals()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx):

**string.CompareTo**:

> Compares this instance with a specified object or String and returns
>   an integer that indicates whether this instance precedes, follows, or
>   appears in the same position in the sort order as the specified object
>   or String.

**string.Equals**:

> Determines whether two String objects have the same value.

In short, `CompareTo` is used for sorting. `Equals` is used to determine equality.

Answer (score 19):

`CompareTo()` tells you which, and if, one is greater/less than the other, while `Equals()` simply tells you if they are equivalent values.

If all you want to know is "are they the same values", you use `Equals()`. If you need to also know how they compare, use `CompareTo()`

```
int a = 50;
int b = 10;

//if you need to know if they are equal:
if(a.Equals(b)){
    //won't execute
}

//this would check if they are equal, as well
if(a.CompareTo(b) == 0){
    //won't execute
}

//if you need to know if a is bigger than b, specifically:
if(a.CompareTo(b) > 0){
    //will execute
}

//this would check to see if a is less than b
if(a.CompareTo(b) < 0){
    //won't execute
}
```

Finally, note that these `Equals()` and `CompareTo()` methods are not strictly needed for primitive types like `int`, because the standard comparison operators are overloaded, so you could do these:

```
//this would check if they are equal, as well
if(a == b){
    //won't execute
}

//if you need to know if a is bigger than b, specifically:
if(a > b){
    //will execute
}

//this would check to see if a is less than b
if(a < b){
    //won't execute
}
```

Finally, you mentioned `string` in your question. `Equals()` and `CompareTo()` work as I have describe for `string` as well. Just keep in mind the 'comparison' that `CompareTo()` does on strings is based on alphabetical sorting, so `"abcdefg" < "z"`

Comment: thx! so if we just want to see if they are the same values, use Equals() will outperform than CompareTo()? What da the adv. of using Equals?

Comment: There *may* be some tiny performance difference, I guess. If you just need to know equality, yes; use `Equals()`. It's also more clear in your code to check `a.Equals(b)` than `a.CompareTo(b) == 0`

Comment: The real advantage is that not objects provide a `CompareTo` method. `Equals` will always be there, as it's provided by the base `Object` class.

Answer (score 6):

The functionality in `CompareTo` is actually a superset of functionality of `Equals`.  A `CompareTo` function dictates ordering, before, after or equals while the `Equals` function merely dictates equality.  Hence it's actually possible to define `Equals` in terms of `CompareTo`

```
public bool Equals(string other) {
  return 0 == CompareTo(other);
}
```

Comment: Although a common case, this isn't always the case. A typical example is where `CompareTo()` only checks the name of an object to determine ordering while `Equals()` might check other fields as well. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx): "This current instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as the object specified by the CompareTo method." - it does not say that the object is equal.

Answer (score 5):

`Equals` will return a boolean for equality.

`CompareTo` will return an int, with -1 (or any other negative value) for "less than", 0 for "equals", or 1 (or any other positive value) for "greater than".  This method is useful for sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Equality can be “fussier” than comparison, but not vice versa.
CompareTo can say “All objects are equal”
while Equals says “But some are more equal than others!”

An example of this is System.String. String’s Equals method and == operator
use ordinal comparison, which compares the Unicode point values of each character.
Its CompareTo method, however, uses a less fussy culture-dependent comparison. On
most computers, for instance, the strings “ṻ” and “ǖ” are different according to
Equals, but the same according to CompareTo.

This is from [C# in a nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104)

Answer (score -2):

CompareTo method is comparing instance of object with parameter of String object.
Equals method determine the value of both are the same or not.

CompareTo should be used when you are comparing two objects' values.

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = "def"
if(strq.CompareTo(str2) //
```

Equals should be used when either one or both are not objects.

```
string str1 = "abc";
if(str1.Equals("abc") //
```

If you use CompareTo method for normal value type variables, it will use type cast (boxing) which is not necessary.